# Proof of Ramanujan doubly exponential series identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, gamma-function, fourier-transform

Apologies if this has been asked here already. On page 7 of [this paper](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/aachen.pdf) the following formula due to [Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) is presented:

$$\alpha \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-n e^{k\alpha}}=\alpha\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}n^k}{k!(e^{k\alpha}-1)}\right)-\gamma-\ln{n}+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\varphi(k\beta)$$

where:

$$\varphi(\beta)=\frac{1}{\beta}\Im\left(n^{-i\beta}\Gamma(i\beta+1)\right)$$

and $\alpha, n>0$, for any $\beta>0$ such that $\alpha\beta=2\pi$. No proof is presented there although it is mentioned that [Poisson's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) can be used, with the note that the proof is 'intricate' (although it seems to imply that Ramanujan used properties of the [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) to prove it). The theorem is also mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1186074/284973), which mentions that the proof can be found [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02830888), but like the author of that answer I do not have access to this paper. I have tried to prove this myself, but I have not had luck using the Poisson summation formula directly since I do not know how to find the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of $e^{a e^{bt}}$ (although using functions like $e^{t}e^{-e^t}$ I was able to formally find some vaguely similar summation identities involving [imaginary parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) of [gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)). I was wondering whether anyone knows how to prove this formula?

Comment: possibly you have to use the [Ramanujan master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan's_master_theorem). And the Laplace transform of $e^{-e^u}$  is the Gamma function

Comment: @user1952009 Possibly. I am not sure how the Laplace transform would help though.

Comment: You asked for the Fourier transform... You didn't know it was the same  as the Laplace transform ?

Comment: @user1952009 I know that it's very similar, but I thought that it wouldn't be so simple here for $e^{-e^u}$ because of the way that function behaves at $u\rightarrow-\infty$. Wolfram Alpha didn't help me here.

Comment: This is one of the strangest formulas by Ramanujan whose proof (as given in paper by Berndt) is not difficult. I wonder what Hardy would have said if this were also present in Ramanujan's letter to Hardy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See whether this link helps you: http://documentslide.com/documents/two-remarkable-doubly-exponential-series-transformations-of-ramanujan.html

Comment: I eventually get a 502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: I tried again later and got the paper, thanks! I'll accept the answer, but I can't upvote it at the moment 'cos I've passed the daily vote limit.